# Java Optional interface: Nested conditions on Optional object chain

Tags: java, option-type

I'd like to write again this code a complete `Optional` fluent methods in order to do that:

```
Optional<Reference> reference = this.referenceService.get(id);
if (!reference.isPresent()) {
    return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
}

EntityTag entityTag = this.eTag(reference.get());
ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = this.request.evaluatePreconditions(entityTag);

if (Objects.isNull(responseBuilder)) {
    responseBuilder = Response
        .ok()
        .entity(reference.get())
        .cacheControl(this.cacheControl)
        .tag(entityTag);
}

return responseBuilder.build();
```

Up to now, I've been able to do that:

```
return this.referenceService.get(id)
    .map(this::eTag)
    .map(this.request::evaluatePreconditions)
    .orElse(Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND))
    .cacheControl(this.cacheControl)
    .tag(this.eTag(this.referenceService.get(id).get()))
    .build();
```

But this code is not the same the previous one.

I've two conditions to handle:

```
if (!reference.isPresent()) {
    return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
}
```

and

```
if (Objects.isNull(responseBuilder)) {
```

I don't quite figure out how to solve that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not something meant to be solved in a chain of operations in a single pipeline. For instance, you have at least three branched output.

Comment: I have literally tried 12 minutes to put up a solution and once I did, I hated it, I admit I agree with @Naman

Comment: I also agree. My question is then, how a functional language solves that. I don't think it's not possible using lisp...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first condition `if (!reference.isPresent())` is covered by `.orElse(Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND))`

To cover the second condition `if (Objects.isNull(responseBuilder))`
 make an Optional from the result of `this.request.evaluatePreconditions(entityTag)` and then an `orElseGet` to return the `ok` builder

The below code is written from the top of my head, I didn't test it

```
this.referenceService
    .get(id)
    .map(this::eTag)
    .map(entityTag -> Optional.ofNullable(this.request.evaluatePreconditions(entityTag))
                                .orElseGet(() -> Response.ok()
                                                        .entity(entityTag)
                                                        .cacheControl(this.cacheControl)
                                                        .tag(entityTag)))
    .orElse(Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND))
    .buld();
```

To simplify the expression the `Optional.ofNullable(...).orElseGet(...)` part could be refactored in a method and call that method instead of having all inline

Something like below

```
private ResponseBuilder getBuilderOrDefault(EntityTag entityTag) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(this.request.evaluatePreconditions(entityTag))
                   .orElseGet(() -> Response.ok()
                                            .entity(entityTag)
                                            .cacheControl(this.cacheControl)
                                            .tag(entityTag));
}
```

The mapping will become

```
this.referenceService
    .get(id)
    .map(this::eTag)
    .map(this::getBuilderOrDefault)
    .orElse(Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND))
    .buld();
```